# Javascript in content editor web part not working after publishing the page

Tags: javascript, publishing-page, content-editor-web-part

I have a publishing page in which I have placed content editor web part which contains the link to redirect the user to application page.

Code in the content editor web part is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirectToDownloadsPage() {
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
        var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
        var myItems = '';
        var i;

        for (i in items) {
            myItems += '|' + items[i].id;
        }

        if (myItems) {        
            var siteUrl = url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/DownloadImages.aspx?Items=" + myItems;        
            window.location.href = siteUrl
        }
        else {
            alert("Select atleast one item");
        }
    }, "SP.js");
 }
</script>
<a onclick="return redirectToDownloadsPage();" href="#"> Download Images </a>
```

My problem is when I edit the page and click on the link JavaScript works, then I check in the page then also the JavaScript works fine but when I publish the page the JavaScript does not work.

I am getting no items in the `item` in JavaScript.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you try using ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded? It seems like SP.js is not loading or loading at last.

Comment: As a part of the new Minimal Download Strategy (MDS), sp.js is not loaded by default on published pages. 

You will have to load your sp.js explicitly from the /_layouts/15 directory.

Comment: Thank you for response sir, now to make some experiments I removed the content editor web part and added Script Editor web part. And placed the above code (see the code in post). But it works until the page is published. And after publishing the page I am getting the error: `Unable to get property 'Selection' of undefined or null reference` @Amit

Comment: The same error occurred when I place content editor web part

Comment: Do you have any idea about this issue sir? @Amit

Comment: There is a typo in your example, the missing closing bracket for a function.

Comment: try the below code. Let me know if alert is firing after publishing the page.   $(document).ready(function(){ var fileUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/sp.js"; $.getScript(fileUrl,function(){ alert('Started'); }); });

Comment: MDS causes all sorts of JS execution irregularities... If you are actually using 2013 with MDS enabled can you try accessing the page with its normal URL and see if it works as expected? -- use the http://<site>/SitePages/page.aspx format instead of http://<site>/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/page.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
In the Content Editor WebPart put the following:

```
<script src="/sites/test/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/sites/test/_layouts/15/SP.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/sites/test//sites/test/SiteAssets/Scripts/Script.js" type="text/javascript">

<a onclick="return redirectToDownloadsPage();" href="#"> Download Images </a>
```

Now create a folder **Scripts** in the **SiteAssets** and put [jquery-1.11.1.min.js](http://jquery.com/) and **Script.js** file in that. Which will contain following code:

```
 function redirectToDownloadsPage() {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
    var myItems = '';
    var i;

    for (i in items) {
        myItems += '|' + items[i].id;
    }

    if (myItems) {        
        var siteUrl = url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/DownloadImages.aspx?Items=" + myItems;        
        window.location.href = siteUrl
    }
    else {
        alert("Select atleast one item");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

if all else fails just reference sp.js directly on the master page using:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" Name="sp.js" runat="server"           OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"><SharePoint:ScriptLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, my custom CEWP script was not loading because of url redirection through `_layout/15/start.aspx`.

Just I have de-activated the Minimal download strategy site feature and everything is working as expected. I hope this helps.